# Why would a restaurant called "London Restaurant" in Hong Kong have nothing to do with London or anything British?

Tags: london, hong-kong, restaurants

In an episode of a TV series which was aired in 2017, which by the way has nothing to do with visiting restaurants and doesn't explain this in any way, they are in Hong Kong and find this restaurant called "**London Restaurant**" (see first screenshot) in English letters.

However, entering the restaurant (which oddly requires an elevator to get to inside the building), it looks nothing like anything I would call "London" or "British"; it's got tons of people (all Asians, which is hardly surprising) and lots of noise and stress with "waitresses" pulling and pushing around large metal containers on wheels (containing food). There's numerous tables, bright lighting and the atmosphere truly has nothing to do with London or an English/British environment whatsoever from what I can tell. (See the two more screenshots.)

Why does this restaurant have "London" in its name? Does it even *attempt* to look like something they have seen in London? I'm not a London expert, so maybe I'm all wrong and this is indeed a type of restaurant that they found efficient and have copied to Hong Kong?

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]
[image: screenshot 3]

Comment: Welcome to Travel SE. How is this question related to Travel as defined in the Help page: _https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic_ ? What is the actual problem to be solved?

Comment: All Asians, except the chap in the foreground of the second picture, and the group in the foreground of the third picture. This seems like a rant, how would anyone know why the owners called it "London Restaurant"?

Comment: I have been to restaurants with names unrelated to the food they sell or to their décor. Perhaps the restaurant in question is owned by Mr or Ms London? Perhaps the owner named it after their beloved dog, already named London when they got it? Perhaps they hoped to save up enough money after a lifetime in the restaurant business to afford a visit to London. All of these would be perfectly acceptable, and not even unusual, reasons for naming a business.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a travel question.

Answer (score 11):

I voted to close as opinion based, but couldn't resist a quick search. And presto, the restaurant in question has [a web site](http://www.londonhongkong.co.uk/about-us/our-history/) which says:

> The London Hong Kong Brand started more than 15 years ago in the heart of the infamous London China Town. Today, the brand occupies a prime location near Heathrow.
>   Diners new to the London Hong Kong can expect to receive a traditional yet modern Chinese dining experience from the in-house trained team within an exquisitely designed surrounding.

Trip advisor reviews say the Hong Kong location is an authentic push-trolley dim-sum place, on the 4th floor, which matches your snippets from the TV show.

So the answer appears to be that the owners had a restaurant in London's Chinatown, and now also have one in Hong Kong and are using the same name for locations in both countries. Which turns out not to be surprising or weird at all.

Comment: +1 Not quite sure why they’d describe London’s China Town as ‘infamous’ :-)

Comment: That's not the website of the restaurant, the link you provide is a restaurant in UK and have nothing to do with that restaurant in Hong Kong. The restaurant in Hong Kong is called 倫敦大酒樓 (London Restaurant) and it's own by a guy name 陳茂發 (I guess English is Chen Mao Fa) and the Chinese newspaper said he only have restaurant in Hong Kong.

http://hk.hkcd.com/content/2015-08/05/content_3477368.htm